# Check for int value from a arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following function, where I have to check for a particular value and print some output.
Since I have same operation for multiple int values , I tried using arrayList.

```
public static final List<Integer> randomNumbers = Collections.unmodifiableList(
        new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
            add(7);
            add(9);
            etc...
        }});


public void checkNumbers(int state) {
    //This is existing
    if (state == 7 || state == 9) {
        //do something
    }

    // I can use this
    if (state == randomNumbers.get(0) || state == randomNumbers.get(1)) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Is there any other simpler way to compare the entire arraylist ?

Comment: swtich-case statement seems to be handy, if you cannot compute the values in any way

Comment: tried something like contains?

Comment: using `contains` results in boolean, right ?

Comment: Indeed. would that suit your needs? If not indexOf() can also help

Comment: just remember it will give the index of the first occurrence of the value and will return -1 if it is not there in the list.

Comment: `contains` wont be of help here. I didnt use `indexOf` because it might return -1.

Comment: I think, as of now I can live with `get(0) and get(1)` to check for two values

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use [double brace initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java).

Comment: Thats a really good point. Thank you so much

Comment: @cantona_7 what is it you're trying to do if contains or indexOf can't help?